# Conversion of Array and objects to bulk insert in mysql Sequelize + Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, sequelize.js

This is my json object:

```
    {
    "groups":

 [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "groupname": "Angular",
            "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:05.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:05.000Z",
            "contactgroups": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "12345"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "54321"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "99999"
                }
            }],
            "select": true
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "groupname": "React",
            "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:10.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:10.000Z",
            "contactgroups": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "66666"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "54321"
                }
            }],
            "select": true
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "groupname": "Vue",
            "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:15.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:15.000Z",
            "contactgroups": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "12345"
                }
            }]
        },
     ],
    "sender": "ifelse",
    "message": "test"
}
```

I want to convert above object like this:

```
[
    {"gsm": 12345, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
    {"gsm": 54321, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
    {"gsm": 99999, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
    {"gsm": 66666, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
    {"gsm": 54321, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
    {"gsm": 12345, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},

]
```

Then only i am able to bulk insert in sequelize.

How to do this using for or foreach or any other functions? to done this stuff?

is foreach better? is it possible to do with map?

I want my final json object, then only sequelize allowed to bulk create.

Ps: I want "select": true json gsm numbers only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I am using for loop to make JSON object

```js
 var data={
    "groups":

 [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "groupname": "Angular",
            "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:05.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:05.000Z",
            "contactgroups": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "12345"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "54321"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "99999"
                }
            }],
            "select": true
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "groupname": "React",
            "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:10.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:10.000Z",
            "contactgroups": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "66666"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "54321"
                }
            }],
            "select": true
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "groupname": "Vue",
            "createdAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:15.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-12-05T09:36:15.000Z",
            "contactgroups": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "contact":
                {
                    "gsm": "12345"
                }
            }]
        },
     ],
    "sender": "ifelse",
    "message": "test"
 }


    var result=[
        {"gsm": 12345, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
        {"gsm": 54321, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
        {"gsm": 99999, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
        {"gsm": 66666, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
        {"gsm": 54321, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},
        {"gsm": 12345, "sender": "ifelse", "message": "test"},

    ]
    var arr=[];
    for(var i=0;i<data.groups.length;i++){
       if(data.groups[i].select){
        for(var j=0;j<data.groups[i].contactgroups.length;j++){    arr.push({gsm:data.groups[i].contactgroups[j].contact.gsm,sender:data.sender,message:data.message});    
        }
       }
    }
    console.log(arr);
```

Comment: bro, its worked, but slightly little bit change in question, shall i edit this question now? or post new question and post that link here?

Comment: see my json object in question now

Comment: there is select: true, i want to get gsm numbers only from select : true

Answer (score 2):

Try with `lodash`

```
var result = _.flatten(data.groups.map( r => r.contactgroups))
              .map(r => ({ gsm: r.contact.gsm, sender: "ifelse", message: "test" })
);

console.log(result);
```

Update #2 - With filter

```
var result = _.flatten(_.filter(data.groups,{'select': true }).map( r => r.contactgroups))
              .map(r => ({ gsm: r.contact.gsm, sender: "ifelse", message: "test" })
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: nice :)  I want "select": true json gsm numbers only